# Некорректное выравнивание удалённых сообщений

Tags: дефект, дизайн, ответы, адаптивный-дизайн

При уменьшении ширины окна, когда третья колонка переносится вниз, вторая сдвигается немного влево и пересекает вертикальную линию. На удалённых ответах хорошо заметно:

[image: скриншот]

Comment: а кстати кто программирует  это все?

Comment: @Антон, американские разработчики. Точнее, в основном американские.

Comment: А, а они читают это?

Comment: @Антон, теоретически - да, но лучше на их мете писать. Но мне лень.

Comment: ♦  программисты - люди ленивые

Comment: @Антон, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303062/309650